# Inserting data from multiple form to coresponding colums in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple table generated form a table:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="inventarioDone.php">
<?php


mysql_select_db("tierra") or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventario ") 
or die(mysql_error());  

echo "<table border='1' padding='2' cellspacing='0' ";
echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>Nombre</th> <th>Cantidad</th> </tr>";
// 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    // 
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo $row['idItem'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .  $row['nombreItem'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "</td> <td>";
    echo '<input type="number" name="' . $row['idItem'] . '" id="' . $row['idItem'] .'" value="">"';   
    echo "</td></tr>";



} 

echo "</table>";
echo "<br>";
?>


<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

And Im trying to insert value from the form into table "inventarioStat" where each column correspond to the "idItem". this is my code:

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST["nombreItem"]) && count($_POST['nombreItem'])>0) {

    foreach($_POST["nombreItem"] as $key => $value) {
        $itemsID = $_POST['1'] ++;
        $value = $_POST["ticketValue"][$key];
        $query = "INSERT INTO `inventarioStat` SET $itemsID = `$_POST[1] 1++` ";
         mysql_query($query);
    }     

}

?>
```

The ids in the 'inventarioStat' go: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 etc... so thats why Im putting ++ to increase each time.
I hope I explained what Im trying to do here.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what problem are you running into? without trying the code i would suggest you don't have numbers as ids in your form.

Comment: Since you already have the `++` in `$itemsID = $_POST['1'] ++;` you don't have to repeat it in your `SET` because this will increase it again. 
You can probably just do `SET itemsID = '$itemsID'` --- your `SET itemsID` is incorrect having the `$` in front of `itemsID` since that is (might be) your column name.

Comment: I know its bad practice using number for Ids but thats my unique Ids of the product, so I need to use the number. Also Im trying to match ids of the item with corresponding column.